# My tool bar items icon are not showing in Xamarin Ios

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Im new into developing Xamarin apps, and I'm trying to implement a Toolbar with icons and it Android works properly but not with ios, only the 1st icon is showed. I think the code is not necessary because it quite simple but I will post it:

```
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems >
    <ToolbarItem  Text="Add act" Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked" IconImageSource="anadir.png" Priority="1" />
    <ToolbarItem Text="Add al" Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked" IconImageSource="adduser.png"/>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Buscar" Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked"  IconImageSource="buscar.png"/>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Mostrar" Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked" IconImageSource="lista.png"/>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Eliminar" Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked" IconImageSource="cerrar.png" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

By the way, Toolbar Items are out of Toolbar
The rest of images of the app works properly.

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue,five icons are showed on my side,could you show a screenshot ? And what's your Xamarin.Fomrs version ?

Comment: Have your tried adding priority property for each of the items? Currently you only assign it to one, this could be the reason why.